# cron jobs not working aws whenever gem rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, cron, whenever

I know this is a very common question but I feel like I need a specific answer to help find out where I am going wrong...

Loaded whenever gem to manage cron jobs - it works fine in development but when I loaded the app into AWS I can't seem to it work...

When I SSH into the instance I can run crontab -l and it lists the whenever tasks but it just doesn't seem to actually execute them. I also cant find any log files to read into why it's not firing.

This is what I pulled from the eb activity log..

```
+++ GEM_ROOT=/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
++ ((  0 != 0  ))
+ cd /var/app/current
+ su -c 'bundle exec whenever --update-cron'
[write] crontab file updated
+ su -c 'crontab -l'


# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: 
/var/app/current/config/schedule.rb at: 2018-01-10 06:08:24 +0000
0 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /var/app/current && bundle exec 
bin/rails runner -e production '\''Trendi.home'\'' >> 
app/views/pages/cron.html.erb 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: 
/var/app/current/config/schedule.rb at: 2018-01-10 06:08:24 +0000
[2018-01-10T06:08:24.705Z] INFO  [15603] - [Application update app-
a3a0-180109_230627@16/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Completed 
activity. Result:
Successfully execute hooks in directory 
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post.
```

This is my config file from ebextensions folder

```
files:
    "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/01_cron.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
       #!/usr/bin/env bash
       # Using similar syntax as the appdeploy pre hooks that is 
       managed by AWS
       set -xe

       EB_SCRIPT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container 
       -k script_dir)
       EB_SUPPORT_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container 
       -k support_dir)
       EB_DEPLOY_DIR=$(/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config container 
       -k app_deploy_dir)

       . $EB_SUPPORT_DIR/envvars
       . $EB_SCRIPT_DIR/use-app-ruby.sh

       cd $EB_DEPLOY_DIR
       su -c "bundle exec whenever --update-cron"
       su -c "crontab -l"
```

My Schedule.rb

```
      ENV['RAILS_ENV'] = "production"
      set :output, "app/views/pages/cron.html.erb"
      every 1.hour, at: ":00"do # 1.minute 1.day 1.week 1.month 1.year 
      is also supported
       runner "Trendi.home", :environment => 'production'
      end
```

And my task that is stored at /lib/

```
   module Trendi
    def self.home
     #exectuted task code here
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try a simpler command in your crontab and change it to fire every minute. E.g.

> /bin/echo "test" >> /home/username/testcron.log

That way you can quickly rule out if it's the cronjob that's the culprit. Keep in mind to use full paths to each command. So in your case you might want to change the "bundle" command to use the full path. You can find the path with the "which" command.

Also, are you sure you are correctly escaping here?

> -e production '\''Trendi.home'\''

Wouldn't this be more adequate?

> -e production "Trendi.home"

Comment: Well I am not writing directly to cron as I'm using whenever gem to handle that. Is there a way to check aws logs to see if cron is firing? Outside of the cron logs that I have specified in the schedule.rb